# Adding timestamps via named pipes or rsyslog to the log output of a systemd-managed service

Tags: logging, systemd, named-pipes, mkfifo

I'm having to deal with a proprietary legacy service (running on Debian 10) that logs various (roughly) INFO and NOTICE level things things into stdout, and (roughly) WARNING and ERROR level things into stderr. Both can be written to files using the `--stdout <path>` and `--stderr <path>` command line parameters. Our systemd unit file for this daemon looks like this (pruned down to the bare essentials):

```
[Unit]
Description=Some legacy proprietary thing
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/thing \
  --stdout /var/log/thing/stdout.log \
  --stderr /var/log/thing/stderr.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem is that the lines written to stdout.log and stderr.log do not contain timestamps, which we now need. The application is a black box to us, and modifying its logging output to include timestamps is not feasible.

In my research, I've come across two options that might work here. If you have others, I'd be keen to hear them.

**OPTION 1**

Create named pipes with `mkfifo` for both stdout and stderr, and make the legacy application use those as the `--stdout` and `--stderr` targets. Then, set up a process to read those pipes, piping each line to the `ts` command, which adds a nice timestamp, like this:

```
$ echo foo | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%.S]'
[2021-08-10 16.16.21.506571] foo
```

It is these timestamped lines that would then get written to log files, one for stdout and one for stderr, probably via piping.

**OPTION 2**

In the systemd unit file, we might be able to set `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` to `syslog`, and then set `SyslogIdentifier` to some string that we could use with rsyslog, adding a timestamp and writing the final row out to a log file.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to make systemd distinguish stdout and stderr: they would both just be sent to rsyslog without any information about which one was the origin. (I'm aware of `SyslogLevelPrefix`, but that requires the incoming log messages from our black box application to contain `sd-daemon(3)` style prefixes, and this is currently not feasible.)

**DETAILS**

Due to the problems inherent with option 2, I'll discuss option 1 further. If you know of a workaround to the syslog approach, do share nonetheless.

So, named pipes are great, but I don't know how to implement them in a systemd unit file. I imagine I'll have to have two separate reader processes, one for the stdout pipe and one for the stderr pipe, and therefore two new unit files. Some further notes:

- The named pipes should exist before the writer application starts. I can create them with `mkfifo` beforehand, so this should not be a problem. It shouldn't be necessary to manage the pipes' existence with systemd, unless it makes the unit file(s) simpler or more robust somehow.
- The reader processes that do the timestamp augmentation and log file writing should be up and running before the writer application starts up, which is a job for `Before/After` and `Requires/Wants` in the unit files, I believe.
- The whole apparatus should survive restarts of either the writer application or the reader processes. E.g. if `cat` is used in a reader process, the writer quits and `cat` sees EOF and quits, the reader process should come back up and be ready when the writer process comes back up.
- Any log rows written to the named pipes by the application while the respective reader processes are down are lost, but this is acceptable.

With the writer process having the parameters `--stdout /path/to/outfifo --stderr /path/to/errfifo`, the reader processes could, in theory, be as simple as this:

```
cat /path/to/outfifo | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%.S]' > /var/log/thing/stdout_ts.log
cat /path/to/errfifo | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%.S]' > /var/log/thing/stderr_ts.log
```

Add to that a `logrotate` rule with `copytruncate`, and we're golden! Except I don't know how to do this in a systemd unit file, while satisfying the above restartability requirements.

If you can help with the unit file construction, or suggest an alternative approach, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`journald` can add timestamps, etc. for you.

A simple solution would be to use [`systemd-cat`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-cat.html):

```
ExecStart=/bin/systemd-cat \
  --priority=info \
  --stderr-priority=warning \
  --identifier=thing \
  /usr/local/bin/thing
```

If your `thing` emits logger prefixes for the priority levels (e.g. the line starts with `<4>` for `warning` messages) then you can use the `--level-prefix` flag instead of manually setting the priorities.

Some other ideas include:

- Using [stream logging](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.service.html#Stream%20logging) in your Unit.
- Writing a custom splitter to read in the logs and pipe them to `systemd-cat` with the correct levels.  You would run this as a service that `thing` would talk to.
- Variant: Write a custom parser and send the parsed logs directly to journald via `sd_journal_send(3)`.  You would use systemd to pipe the output of `thing` to the `parser`.
- Use systemd to write stdout and stderr to [a socket unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html#) via the `StandardOutput=` and `StandardError=`.

Comment: Huh, I've never heard of `systemd-cat` before. Seems extremely useful here. Needs some more work on my part but that with the other ideas here are good enough. Accepted and bounty awarded.